# Installation wxWidgets with mingw64

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I try to get wxWidgets installed on a Windows7 x64 Machine but wxWidgets Installation doesn't even work, I cannot get a Hello World App running.

I found out there are several ways to get the library installed and I tried some of them (with Cygwin and the included mingw64 compiler, with mingw64 using diffrent settings), all the time I get Errors while building the library. Could somebody point me out what's wrong with my current setup (which was also my first try) or show another solution?

First I installed mingw64 with the online installer to `c:/mingw64`. I tried some different setups concerning Version and Threads, but ended up with 4.9.2, x86_64, posix Threads, sjlj Exceptions.
Then I downloaded MYSYS from sourceforge.net and extracted it to `C:/mysys`.

Then I created a folder `C:/wxWidgets` and mounted it as `/wxWidgets`, downloaded the wxWidgets 3.0.2 source and put in into my `mysys-home` folder.

From `/wxWidgets` I executed: `/home/Martin/wxWidgets-3.0.2/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-shared --enable-monolithic`

The configure did his job without errors though some libraries couldn't be found and built-in libraries were taken instead (jpeg, png, regex, tiff, expat).

Then I executed `make` and it ran for some minutes and suddenly crashed. The only output was make: `*** [monolib_any.o] Error 1`

The last executed command was `/wxWidgets/bk-make-pch ./.pch/wxprec_monolib -D__WXMSW__ ...`
Right before, there is an note concerning POSIX paths: "CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning...

All the other tries ended up like this one, make suddenly hung up. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the make/compile process really dies without any other error messages, the most likely explanations are that either it runs out of memory (but even then normally there would be some error message) or some hardware problem, it's really not supposed to do this on a working machine.

So my advice would be to run some hardware diagnostics. If this shows nothing, run `make -n` and execute the command used to compile `any.cpp` by hand by copy and pasting it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. What I did now was trying the mingw32-make command with some options i found on the net.

Comment: Sorry, editing took too log, here is the complete comment: Thanks for your advice. What I did now was trying the mingw32-make command from the mysys terminal inside the msw folder with some options i found on the net. The command was mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc CFG=64 CPP="gcc -E -D_M_AMD64" DEBUG_FLAG=0 BUILD=release UNICODE=1 MONOLITHIC=1 USE_OPENGL=1

Comment: As I said, you should really try the compiler line itself, i.e. what `make -n` shows it would be execute.

Comment: [SOLVED] So, finally I managed to get the libraries compiled. I used the TDM-GCC-64 package, mysys and used make with the options provided by https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse,_CDT_%26_MingW_Setup_Guide#Installation_2 - Thanks for your help.